# How can I save the view to sort by CPU usage?

Tags: htop

Can I somehow modify `htop`'s default view to display processes sorted by CPU usage?  I want `htop` to "remember" my view/sort method.

If it's relevant, I'm currently on Xubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run `htop`, press <kbd>F6</kbd>, select `CPU%`.

Quit by using <kbd>F10</kbd>

If it doesn't remember your settings check your `~/.config/htop/htoprc` file if it is writable by your user. You might make it writable like this:

```
chown $USER ~/.config/htop/htoprc
```

Or you can try removing it and let `htop` generate a new one, maybe the old one is corrupted somehow.

```
rm ~/.config/htop/htoprc
```

Comment: Thank you. Well the thing is, the next time I run `htop`, it doesn't remember my selection.

Comment: @henry I updated my answer. Still doesn't help?

Comment: Deleted the file, it's now sorted by CPU by default. Again, that is, don't know why it wouldn't switch back. Thank you.

Comment: Also, to save your settings when you quit, use F10 to quit instead of pressing q.

Answer (score 11):

I noticed I had to actually quit properly using <kbd>F10</kbd> and not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for htop to save the sort by column.

Comment: Please make sure to write a complete answer instead of a partial one. Even though others may have provided the information doesn't mean it should be left out of your answer. You could also leave a comment in case you just wanted to let the poster know.

Comment: Whats wrong with my answer??

Comment: It's probably best to mention how to change the sort order in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Other solutions are better, but if all else fails, you can make an alias for `htop -s PERCENT_CPU`.

Comment: This is useful when its not possible to transmit the F6 keypress - such as when connecting via Putty (Windows)

Comment: @svandragt Maybe I have a newer version of putty, but the F6 key is working on windows 7 with putty.